# How to create/update items in a list based on items added/updated in another list based on Created By

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, jsom, flow

I have two lists: Comp Request and Record List. 
Comp List contains a calculated column called 'Total Credit'. The list itself contains a SP OOTB new item form which user fills in and a flow runs for approval process. Each user submits at least one request a month so let's say for example for a particular user, there are about three rows of record in Comp List.

Now what I wanna do is, for all three rows of record, i want to get total of 'Total Credit' for that user and copy it in the Record List where I have two text fields as: Employee Name and Total Credit.

For Example, Comp List would something like below:

Created By  - Total Credit

User a       -                1.5

User a       -                 1.5

User a        -  1

User b         - 1

User b      -    1

Record List would look like:
Employee Name -Total Credit

User a    -        4

User b     -       2

Also this should account whenever a list item is added/modified, the record list should get the latest accurate total credit count for a particular user.

is this possible to do in SharePOint online using JSOM, SPD Workflow or maybe FLOW. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the need for the 2nd list due to the fact that you can't have totals on calculated fields? That aside I would recommend a Flow proof of concept as SPD is depricated, and js via content editor web parts is not an option on modern lists

Comment: Hi Kasper, the users will be using classic UI only so if you think JSLink would work, please let me know, will appreciate if you can help me with the code. The second list will be used to perform further operations which I have to implement. I have a flow that will do the rest once I have the above implemented for Records list.

Comment: Hi, just to mention since there are about 22 employee in the tenant, I can potentially hard code/pre-popuate  the Employee Name field in the Record List with all the employees if that makes our life easier.

Comment: As far as I know MS has made no statements regarding when classic mode will no longer be available, but this gives me pause https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-lists-and-libraries-rollout